# How to remove the space between toprule and bottom rule in tables arranged using tabular environment

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, longtable

Am trying to organize my 6 table in two columns and three rows. Have used the tabular environment.

The table fit in the columns as expected. In the first column the bottomrule of the first table concide with the top rule of the second table and so on. But in the second column that doesn't happen. There is some space between the bottom rule and toprule of the next table. How can I remove the space in the second column

my code is as shown below:

```
 \begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{center}
\small
\captionsetup{size=footnotesize}
\captionof{table}{Table\label{tab:table2}}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
{\begin{minipage}{0.4\columnwidth}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{2 eV}\\
\hline\hline
Energy&PP-S&PP-SA&PP-SP&PP-SPA +&PE-SPAE\\
(eV)&($e^{+}$) &($e^{+}$)&($e^{+}$)&($e^{+}$)&$e^{-}$\\
\hline\\
0 & 7.5000E-03 & 9.0000E-03 & 6.9930E-02 & 6.0660E-02 & 2.8111E-01 \\
5 & 7.3200E-03 & 8.7900E-03 & 6.6920E-02 & 5.8050E-02 & 2.6723E-01 \\
10 & 6.7700E-03 & 8.1900E-03 & 5.8600E-02 & 5.0870E-02 & 2.2924E-01 \\
15 & 5.9300E-03 & 7.2500E-03 & 4.6930E-02 & 4.0820E-02 & 1.7682E-01 \\
20 & 4.9500E-03 & 6.1500E-03 & 3.4450E-02 & 3.0130E-02 & 1.2246E-01 \\
30 & 3.0900E-03 & 4.0100E-03 & 1.5700E-02 & 1.4250E-02 & 4.8550E-02 \\
40 & 1.5200E-03 & 2.1400E-03 & 9.7400E-03 & 9.3300E-03 & 3.7720E-02 \\
60 & 1.3650E-04 & 3.2142E-04 & 8.7200E-03 & 7.9300E-03 & 5.1200E-02 \\
90 & 1.4666E-04 & 2.1320E-04 & 3.0700E-03 & 3.2400E-03 & 3.3930E-02 \\
120 & 1.6417E-04 & 4.3369E-04 & 9.1700E-03 & 8.1100E-03 & 5.2060E-02 \\
150 & 1.1707E-04 & 5.7344E-04 & 1.6520E-02 & 1.5290E-02 & 5.1290E-02 \\
179 & 1.1783E-04 & 6.3212E-04 & 9.5540E-02 & 8.6090E-02 & 2.9818E-01 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}}
&
{\begin{minipage}{0.4\columnwidth}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{2.5 eV}\\
\hline\hline
Energy&PP-S&PP-SA&PP-SP&PP-SPA +&PE-SPAE\\
(eV)&($e^{+}$) &($e^{+}$)&($e^{+}$)&($e^{+}$)&$e^{-}$\\
\hline\\
0 & 9.4970E-02 & 8.6140E-02 & 7.6910E-02 & 6.7180E-02 & 5.7540E-02 \\
5 & 8.7050E-02 & 7.8720E-02 & 7.0860E-02 & 6.1670E-02 & 5.2490E-02 \\
10 & 7.3280E-02 & 6.5970E-02 & 6.0720E-02 & 5.2650E-02 & 4.4400E-02 \\
15 & 5.8210E-02 & 5.2160E-02 & 4.9690E-02 & 4.3030E-02 & 3.6020E-02 \\
20 & 4.1410E-02 & 3.6840E-02 & 3.6940E-02 & 3.1940E-02 & 2.6480E-02 \\
30 & 1.6320E-02 & 1.4310E-02 & 1.6300E-02 & 1.4170E-02 & 1.1740E-02 \\
40 & 4.3900E-03 & 3.9500E-03 & 5.0200E-03 & 4.4200E-03 & 3.9100E-03 \\
60 & 3.6779E-04 & 6.7652E-04 & 4.8200E-03 & 4.2100E-03 & 3.4000E-03 \\
90 & 8.6608E-04 & 7.9927E-04 & 3.1000E-03 & 2.8400E-03 & 2.3400E-03 \\
120 & 5.9715E-04 & 4.2726E-04 & 6.6600E-03 & 5.8100E-03 & 4.7700E-03 \\
150 & 4.5604E-04 & 3.2058E-04 & 8.7500E-03 & 8.0300E-03 & 6.7000E-03 \\
179 & 4.3677E-04 & 3.1865E-04 & 3.7120E-02 & 3.3240E-02 & 2.7470E-02 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}}
\\
{\begin{minipage}{0.4\columnwidth}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{4 eV}\\
\hline\hline
Energy&PP-S&PP-SA&PP-SP&PP-SPA +&PE-SPAE\\
(eV)&($e^{+}$) &($e^{+}$)&($e^{+}$)&($e^{+}$)&$e^{-}$\\
\hline\\
0 & 5.7298E-01 & 5.5016E-01 & 1.1880E-02 & 1.1770E-02 & 1.3400E-02 \\
5 & 4.8934E-01 & 4.6909E-01 & 2.0810E-02 & 2.0060E-02 & 1.9100E-02 \\
10 & 3.2654E-01 & 3.1181E-01 & 3.9750E-02 & 3.7990E-02 & 3.2860E-02 \\
15 & 1.8158E-01 & 1.7243E-01 & 5.1740E-02 & 4.9570E-02 & 4.2660E-02 \\
20 & 8.6570E-02 & 8.1660E-02 & 4.9830E-02 & 4.7940E-02 & 4.2040E-02 \\
30 & 1.2440E-02 & 1.1670E-02 & 2.6280E-02 & 2.5410E-02 & 2.3350E-02 \\
40 & 6.9667E-04 & 8.3683E-04 & 1.7960E-02 & 1.7190E-02 & 1.5500E-02 \\
60 & 1.9900E-03 & 1.8900E-03 & 1.7080E-02 & 1.6220E-02 & 1.4370E-02 \\
90 & 1.0200E-03 & 8.6751E-04 & 5.9800E-03 & 5.5900E-03 & 4.9800E-03 \\
120 & 2.7382E-04 & 2.1843E-04 & 5.5100E-03 & 5.1600E-03 & 4.4200E-03 \\
150 & 6.6697E-05 & 5.3188E-05 & 3.6600E-03 & 3.4200E-03 & 2.8800E-03 \\
179 & 2.4671E-05 & 2.1034E-05 & 6.2200E-03 & 5.6900E-03 & 4.5600E-03 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}}
&
{\begin{minipage}{0.4\columnwidth}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{6 eV}\\
\hline\hline
Energy&PP-S&PP-SA&PP-SP&PP-SPA +&PE-SPAE\\
(eV)&($e^{+}$) &($e^{+}$)&($e^{+}$)&($e^{+}$)&$e^{-}$\\
\hline\\
0 & 1.3462E+00 & 1.3165E+00 & 3.0895E-01 & 3.0683E-01 & 3.0356E-01 \\
5 & 9.9261E-01 & 9.6923E-01 & 2.6066E-01 & 2.5818E-01 & 2.5266E-01 \\
10 & 4.6491E-01 & 4.5206E-01 & 1.8738E-01 & 1.8494E-01 & 1.7725E-01 \\
15 & 1.7669E-01 & 1.7086E-01 & 1.2498E-01 & 1.2330E-01 & 1.1675E-01 \\
20 & 5.5270E-02 & 5.3160E-02 & 7.4620E-02 & 7.3710E-02 & 6.9690E-02 \\
30 & 1.7700E-03 & 1.8100E-03 & 2.4720E-02 & 2.4360E-02 & 2.3490E-02 \\
40 & 1.4000E-03 & 1.4400E-03 & 1.8440E-02 & 1.8000E-02 & 1.7160E-02 \\
60 & 2.0900E-03 & 1.9300E-03 & 4.4700E-03 & 4.3400E-03 & 4.2700E-03 \\
90 & 4.2589E-04 & 3.5884E-04 & 7.6401E-04 & 7.3017E-04 & 7.4240E-04 \\
120 & 8.3499E-05 & 6.4916E-05 & 2.4500E-03 & 2.2600E-03 & 2.0600E-03 \\
150 & 2.3065E-05 & 1.7681E-05 & 1.1620E-02 & 1.0910E-02 & 1.0110E-02 \\
179 & 1.1580E-05 & 8.7843E-06 & 1.9180E-02 & 1.7950E-02 & 1.7860E-02 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}}
\\
{\begin{minipage}{0.4\columnwidth}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{8 eV}\\
\hline\hline
Energy&PP-S&PP-SA&PP-SP&PP-SPA +&PE-SPAE\\
(eV)&($e^{+}$) &($e^{+}$)&($e^{+}$)&($e^{+}$)&$e^{-}$\\
\hline\\
0 & 2.0681E+00 & 2.0379E+00 & 8.3816E-01 & 8.3028E-01 & 7.8709E-01 \\
5 & 1.3276E+00 & 1.3066E+00 & 5.3780E-01 & 5.3224E-01 & 5.0531E-01 \\
10 & 4.4213E-01 & 4.3325E-01 & 1.9529E-01 & 1.9306E-01 & 1.8531E-01 \\
15 & 1.2783E-01 & 1.2462E-01 & 7.3720E-02 & 7.3030E-02 & 7.1870E-02 \\
20 & 2.6280E-02 & 2.5510E-02 & 3.7500E-02 & 3.7200E-02 & 3.6990E-02 \\
30 & 3.5382E-04 & 4.4318E-04 & 1.3700E-02 & 1.3480E-02 & 1.2870E-02 \\
40 & 2.6200E-03 & 2.5600E-03 & 3.9800E-03 & 4.0200E-03 & 4.8600E-03 \\
60 & 1.3700E-03 & 1.2600E-03 & 5.7300E-03 & 5.5400E-03 & 4.2200E-03 \\
90 & 1.8669E-04 & 1.5777E-04 & 4.1300E-03 & 3.9800E-03 & 3.0400E-03 \\
120 & 4.9810E-05 & 4.1139E-05 & 3.9300E-03 & 3.8300E-03 & 3.4900E-03 \\
150 & 2.3575E-05 & 1.9512E-05 & 4.2400E-03 & 4.1300E-03 & 3.9600E-03 \\
179 & 7.0379E-06 & 5.1833E-06 & 1.8350E-02 & 1.8090E-02 & 1.9810E-02 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}}
&
{\begin{minipage}{0.4\columnwidth}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{10 eV}\\
\hline\hline
Energy&PP-S&PP-SA&PP-SP&PP-SPA +&PE-SPAE\\
(eV)&($e^{+}$) &($e^{+}$)&($e^{+}$)&($e^{+}$)&$e^{-}$\\
\hline\\
0 & 2.6462E+00 & 2.6176E+00 & 1.3935E+00 & 1.3835E+00 & 1.3693E+00 \\
5 & 1.5237E+00 & 1.5059E+00 & 8.1023E-01 & 8.0398E-01 & 7.9459E-01 \\
10 & 3.6730E-01 & 3.6139E-01 & 2.1753E-01 & 2.1552E-01 & 2.1170E-01 \\
15 & 8.7530E-02 & 8.5710E-02 & 6.0390E-02 & 5.9740E-02 & 5.8150E-02 \\
20 & 1.0530E-02 & 1.0300E-02 & 2.6290E-02 & 2.5970E-02 & 2.5590E-02 \\
30 & 1.4300E-03 & 1.4700E-03 & 1.0410E-02 & 1.0330E-02 & 1.0180E-02 \\
40 & 2.8900E-03 & 2.8100E-03 & 4.1900E-03 & 4.1600E-03 & 3.9100E-03 \\
60 & 8.3774E-04 & 7.7585E-04 & 6.2500E-03 & 6.0900E-03 & 5.7600E-03 \\
90 & 1.0233E-04 & 8.8553E-05 & 5.9300E-03 & 5.7600E-03 & 5.5300E-03 \\
120 & 3.4667E-05 & 3.0188E-05 & 3.0400E-03 & 2.9600E-03 & 2.8500E-03 \\
150 & 1.5723E-05 & 1.3463E-05 & 4.2400E-03 & 4.1800E-03 & 3.8700E-03 \\
179 & 3.4073E-06 & 3.4427E-06 & 5.9900E-03 & 6.0000E-03 & 5.4200E-03 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE -- can you share some LaTeX code that shows the problem?  Not your whole document, just enough of a [small working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to show the problem.

Comment: \vspace (vertical space) with a negative value?

Comment: The code attached

Answer (score 3):

In the second table column you have different number/type of the horizontal rules as in the first column.

**Edit:**
However, I would rather write your table on the following way:

- remove `\resizebox` (using it the control on the font size in the table is lost)
- for columns use `S` columns defined in the `siunitx` package
- for horizontal lines use only rules defined in the `booktabs` package
- determining of the spaces between columns left to macro `\extracolsep`
- use font size `scriptsize`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \scriptsize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \sisetup{table-format=0.4e1,
             output-exponent-marker=\text{E}
             }
\caption{Table\label{tab:table2}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} C@{\quad}C @{} }
    \toprule
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                             S[table-format=3.0] *{5}{S}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\SI{2}{eV}}    \\
    \midrule
{Energy} &{PP-S}        &{PP-SA}    &{PP-SP}    &{PP-SPA+}  &{PE-SPAE}    \\
{(eV)}   &{($e^{+}$)}   &{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{$e^{-}$}    \\
    \midrule
0   & 7.5000e-03 & 9.0000E-03 & 6.9930E-02 & 6.0660E-02 & 2.8111E-01 \\
5   & 7.3200E-03 & 8.7900E-03 & 6.6920E-02 & 5.8050E-02 & 2.6723E-01 \\
10  & 6.7700E-03 & 8.1900E-03 & 5.8600E-02 & 5.0870E-02 & 2.2924E-01 \\
15  & 5.9300E-03 & 7.2500E-03 & 4.6930E-02 & 4.0820E-02 & 1.7682E-01 \\
20  & 4.9500E-03 & 6.1500E-03 & 3.4450E-02 & 3.0130E-02 & 1.2246E-01 \\
30  & 3.0900E-03 & 4.0100E-03 & 1.5700E-02 & 1.4250E-02 & 4.8550E-02 \\
40  & 1.5200E-03 & 2.1400E-03 & 9.7400E-03 & 9.3300E-03 & 3.7720E-02 \\
60  & 1.3650E-04 & 3.2142E-04 & 8.7200E-03 & 7.9300E-03 & 5.1200E-02 \\
90  & 1.4666E-04 & 2.1320E-04 & 3.0700E-03 & 3.2400E-03 & 3.3930E-02 \\
120 & 1.6417E-04 & 4.3369E-04 & 9.1700E-03 & 8.1100E-03 & 5.2060E-02 \\
150 & 1.1707E-04 & 5.7344E-04 & 1.6520E-02 & 1.5290E-02 & 5.1290E-02 \\
179 & 1.1783E-04 & 6.3212E-04 & 9.5540E-02 & 8.6090E-02 & 2.9818E-01 
\end{tabular*}
    &   \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             S[table-format=3.0] *{5}{S}}
    \toprule
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\SI{2.5}{eV}}\\
            \midrule
{Energy} &{PP-S}        &{PP-SA}    &{PP-SP}    &{PP-SPA+}  &{PE-SPAE}    \\
{(eV)}   &{($e^{+}$)}   &{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{$e^{-}$}    \\
            \midrule
0   & 9.4970E-02 & 8.6140E-02 & 7.6910E-02 & 6.7180E-02 & 5.7540E-02 \\
5   & 8.7050E-02 & 7.8720E-02 & 7.0860E-02 & 6.1670E-02 & 5.2490E-02 \\
10  & 7.3280E-02 & 6.5970E-02 & 6.0720E-02 & 5.2650E-02 & 4.4400E-02 \\
15  & 5.8210E-02 & 5.2160E-02 & 4.9690E-02 & 4.3030E-02 & 3.6020E-02 \\
20  & 4.1410E-02 & 3.6840E-02 & 3.6940E-02 & 3.1940E-02 & 2.6480E-02 \\
30  & 1.6320E-02 & 1.4310E-02 & 1.6300E-02 & 1.4170E-02 & 1.1740E-02 \\
40  & 4.3900E-03 & 3.9500E-03 & 5.0200E-03 & 4.4200E-03 & 3.9100E-03 \\
60  & 3.6779E-04 & 6.7652E-04 & 4.8200E-03 & 4.2100E-03 & 3.4000E-03 \\
90  & 8.6608E-04 & 7.9927E-04 & 3.1000E-03 & 2.8400E-03 & 2.3400E-03 \\
120 & 5.9715E-04 & 4.2726E-04 & 6.6600E-03 & 5.8100E-03 & 4.7700E-03 \\
150 & 4.5604E-04 & 3.2058E-04 & 8.7500E-03 & 8.0300E-03 & 6.7000E-03 \\
179 & 4.3677E-04 & 3.1865E-04 & 3.7120E-02 & 3.3240E-02 & 2.7470E-02 
        \end{tabular*}       \\
% second row
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             S[table-format=3.0] *{5}{S}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\SI{4}{eV}}    \\
    \midrule
{Energy} &{PP-S}        &{PP-SA}    &{PP-SP}    &{PP-SPA+}  &{PE-SPAE}    \\
{(eV)}   &{($e^{+}$)}   &{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{$e^{-}$}    \\
    \midrule
0   & 5.7298E-01 & 5.5016E-01 & 1.1880E-02 & 1.1770E-02 & 1.3400E-02 \\
5   & 4.8934E-01 & 4.6909E-01 & 2.0810E-02 & 2.0060E-02 & 1.9100E-02 \\
10  & 3.2654E-01 & 3.1181E-01 & 3.9750E-02 & 3.7990E-02 & 3.2860E-02 \\
15  & 1.8158E-01 & 1.7243E-01 & 5.1740E-02 & 4.9570E-02 & 4.2660E-02 \\
20  & 8.6570E-02 & 8.1660E-02 & 4.9830E-02 & 4.7940E-02 & 4.2040E-02 \\
30  & 1.2440E-02 & 1.1670E-02 & 2.6280E-02 & 2.5410E-02 & 2.3350E-02 \\
40  & 6.9667E-04 & 8.3683E-04 & 1.7960E-02 & 1.7190E-02 & 1.5500E-02 \\
60  & 1.9900E-03 & 1.8900E-03 & 1.7080E-02 & 1.6220E-02 & 1.4370E-02 \\
90  & 1.0200E-03 & 8.6751E-04 & 5.9800E-03 & 5.5900E-03 & 4.9800E-03 \\
120 & 2.7382E-04 & 2.1843E-04 & 5.5100E-03 & 5.1600E-03 & 4.4200E-03 \\
150 & 6.6697E-05 & 5.3188E-05 & 3.6600E-03 & 3.4200E-03 & 2.8800E-03 \\
179 & 2.4671E-05 & 2.1034E-05 & 6.2200E-03 & 5.6900E-03 & 4.5600E-03 
\end{tabular*}
    &   \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                     S[table-format=3.0] *{5}{S}}
    \toprule
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\SI{6}{eV}}\\
            \midrule
{Energy} &{PP-S}        &{PP-SA}    &{PP-SP}    &{PP-SPA+}  &{PE-SPAE}    \\
{(eV)}   &{($e^{+}$)}   &{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{$e^{-}$}    \\
            \midrule
0   & 1.3462E+00 & 1.3165E+00 & 3.0895E-01 & 3.0683E-01 & 3.0356E-01 \\
5   & 9.9261E-01 & 9.6923E-01 & 2.6066E-01 & 2.5818E-01 & 2.5266E-01 \\
10  & 4.6491E-01 & 4.5206E-01 & 1.8738E-01 & 1.8494E-01 & 1.7725E-01 \\
15  & 1.7669E-01 & 1.7086E-01 & 1.2498E-01 & 1.2330E-01 & 1.1675E-01 \\
20  & 5.5270E-02 & 5.3160E-02 & 7.4620E-02 & 7.3710E-02 & 6.9690E-02 \\
30  & 1.7700E-03 & 1.8100E-03 & 2.4720E-02 & 2.4360E-02 & 2.3490E-02 \\
40  & 1.4000E-03 & 1.4400E-03 & 1.8440E-02 & 1.8000E-02 & 1.7160E-02 \\
60  & 2.0900E-03 & 1.9300E-03 & 4.4700E-03 & 4.3400E-03 & 4.2700E-03 \\
90  & 4.2589E-04 & 3.5884E-04 & 7.6401E-04 & 7.3017E-04 & 7.4240E-04 \\
120 & 8.3499E-05 & 6.4916E-05 & 2.4500E-03 & 2.2600E-03 & 2.0600E-03 \\
150 & 2.3065E-05 & 1.7681E-05 & 1.1620E-02 & 1.0910E-02 & 1.0110E-02 \\
179 & 1.1580E-05 & 8.7843E-06 & 1.9180E-02 & 1.7950E-02 & 1.7860E-02 
        \end{tabular*}       \\
% third row
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             S[table-format=3.0] *{5}{S}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\SI{8}{eV}}    \\
    \midrule
{Energy} &{PP-S}        &{PP-SA}    &{PP-SP}    &{PP-SPA+}  &{PE-SPAE}    \\
{(eV)}   &{($e^{+}$)}   &{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{$e^{-}$}    \\
    \midrule
0   & 2.0681E+00 & 2.0379E+00 & 8.3816E-01 & 8.3028E-01 & 7.8709E-01 \\
5   & 1.3276E+00 & 1.3066E+00 & 5.3780E-01 & 5.3224E-01 & 5.0531E-01 \\
10  & 4.4213E-01 & 4.3325E-01 & 1.9529E-01 & 1.9306E-01 & 1.8531E-01 \\
15  & 1.2783E-01 & 1.2462E-01 & 7.3720E-02 & 7.3030E-02 & 7.1870E-02 \\
20  & 2.6280E-02 & 2.5510E-02 & 3.7500E-02 & 3.7200E-02 & 3.6990E-02 \\
30  & 3.5382E-04 & 4.4318E-04 & 1.3700E-02 & 1.3480E-02 & 1.2870E-02 \\
40  & 2.6200E-03 & 2.5600E-03 & 3.9800E-03 & 4.0200E-03 & 4.8600E-03 \\
60  & 1.3700E-03 & 1.2600E-03 & 5.7300E-03 & 5.5400E-03 & 4.2200E-03 \\
90  & 1.8669E-04 & 1.5777E-04 & 4.1300E-03 & 3.9800E-03 & 3.0400E-03 \\
120 & 4.9810E-05 & 4.1139E-05 & 3.9300E-03 & 3.8300E-03 & 3.4900E-03 \\
150 & 2.3575E-05 & 1.9512E-05 & 4.2400E-03 & 4.1300E-03 & 3.9600E-03 \\
179 & 7.0379E-06 & 5.1833E-06 & 1.8350E-02 & 1.8090E-02 & 1.9810E-02 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    &   \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                     S[table-format=3.0] *{5}{S}}
    \toprule
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\SI{10}{eV}}\\
            \midrule
{Energy} &{PP-S}        &{PP-SA}    &{PP-SP}    &{PP-SPA+}  &{PE-SPAE}    \\
{(eV)}   &{($e^{+}$)}   &{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{$e^{-}$}    \\
            \midrule
0   & 2.6462E+00 & 2.6176E+00 & 1.3935E+00 & 1.3835E+00 & 1.3693E+00 \\
5   & 1.5237E+00 & 1.5059E+00 & 8.1023E-01 & 8.0398E-01 & 7.9459E-01 \\
10  & 3.6730E-01 & 3.6139E-01 & 2.1753E-01 & 2.1552E-01 & 2.1170E-01 \\
15  & 8.7530E-02 & 8.5710E-02 & 6.0390E-02 & 5.9740E-02 & 5.8150E-02 \\
20  & 1.0530E-02 & 1.0300E-02 & 2.6290E-02 & 2.5970E-02 & 2.5590E-02 \\
30  & 1.4300E-03 & 1.4700E-03 & 1.0410E-02 & 1.0330E-02 & 1.0180E-02 \\
40  & 2.8900E-03 & 2.8100E-03 & 4.1900E-03 & 4.1600E-03 & 3.9100E-03 \\
60  & 8.3774E-04 & 7.7585E-04 & 6.2500E-03 & 6.0900E-03 & 5.7600E-03 \\
90  & 1.0233E-04 & 8.8553E-05 & 5.9300E-03 & 5.7600E-03 & 5.5300E-03 \\
120 & 3.4667E-05 & 3.0188E-05 & 3.0400E-03 & 2.9600E-03 & 2.8500E-03 \\
150 & 1.5723E-05 & 1.3463E-05 & 4.2400E-03 & 4.1800E-03 & 3.8700E-03 \\
179 & 3.4073E-06 & 3.4427E-06 & 5.9900E-03 & 6.0000E-03 & 5.4200E-03 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Since your table is huge, it need very small font size in small page border. This encourage rethink that it may be better

- rotate table (using `sidewaystable`),
- remove all repeating sub-tables row headers,
- remove all unnecessary rules
- use bigger font size  (for example `\small` instead `\scriptsize`)
- use bigger page borders:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \sisetup{table-format=0.4e1,
             output-exponent-marker=\text{E}
             }
\caption{Table\label{tab:table2}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} C@{\quad}C @{} }
    \toprule
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                             S[table-format=3.0] *{5}{S}}
{Energy} &{PP-S}        &{PP-SA}    &{PP-SP}    &{PP-SPA+}  &{PE-SPAE}    \\
{(eV)}   &{($e^{+}$)}   &{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{$e^{-}$}    \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\SI{2}{eV}}    \\
    \midrule
0   & 7.5000e-03 & 9.0000E-03 & 6.9930E-02 & 6.0660E-02 & 2.8111E-01 \\
5   & 7.3200E-03 & 8.7900E-03 & 6.6920E-02 & 5.8050E-02 & 2.6723E-01 \\
10  & 6.7700E-03 & 8.1900E-03 & 5.8600E-02 & 5.0870E-02 & 2.2924E-01 \\
15  & 5.9300E-03 & 7.2500E-03 & 4.6930E-02 & 4.0820E-02 & 1.7682E-01 \\
20  & 4.9500E-03 & 6.1500E-03 & 3.4450E-02 & 3.0130E-02 & 1.2246E-01 \\
30  & 3.0900E-03 & 4.0100E-03 & 1.5700E-02 & 1.4250E-02 & 4.8550E-02 \\
40  & 1.5200E-03 & 2.1400E-03 & 9.7400E-03 & 9.3300E-03 & 3.7720E-02 \\
60  & 1.3650E-04 & 3.2142E-04 & 8.7200E-03 & 7.9300E-03 & 5.1200E-02 \\
90  & 1.4666E-04 & 2.1320E-04 & 3.0700E-03 & 3.2400E-03 & 3.3930E-02 \\
120 & 1.6417E-04 & 4.3369E-04 & 9.1700E-03 & 8.1100E-03 & 5.2060E-02 \\
150 & 1.1707E-04 & 5.7344E-04 & 1.6520E-02 & 1.5290E-02 & 5.1290E-02 \\
179 & 1.1783E-04 & 6.3212E-04 & 9.5540E-02 & 8.6090E-02 & 2.9818E-01 
\end{tabular*}
    &   \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             S[table-format=3.0] *{5}{S}}
{Energy} &{PP-S}        &{PP-SA}    &{PP-SP}    &{PP-SPA+}  &{PE-SPAE}    \\
{(eV)}   &{($e^{+}$)}   &{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{($e^{+}$)}&{$e^{-}$}    \\
            \midrule
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\SI{2.5}{eV}}\\
             \midrule
0   & 9.4970E-02 & 8.6140E-02 & 7.6910E-02 & 6.7180E-02 & 5.7540E-02 \\
5   & 8.7050E-02 & 7.8720E-02 & 7.0860E-02 & 6.1670E-02 & 5.2490E-02 \\
10  & 7.3280E-02 & 6.5970E-02 & 6.0720E-02 & 5.2650E-02 & 4.4400E-02 \\
15  & 5.8210E-02 & 5.2160E-02 & 4.9690E-02 & 4.3030E-02 & 3.6020E-02 \\
20  & 4.1410E-02 & 3.6840E-02 & 3.6940E-02 & 3.1940E-02 & 2.6480E-02 \\
30  & 1.6320E-02 & 1.4310E-02 & 1.6300E-02 & 1.4170E-02 & 1.1740E-02 \\
40  & 4.3900E-03 & 3.9500E-03 & 5.0200E-03 & 4.4200E-03 & 3.9100E-03 \\
60  & 3.6779E-04 & 6.7652E-04 & 4.8200E-03 & 4.2100E-03 & 3.4000E-03 \\
90  & 8.6608E-04 & 7.9927E-04 & 3.1000E-03 & 2.8400E-03 & 2.3400E-03 \\
120 & 5.9715E-04 & 4.2726E-04 & 6.6600E-03 & 5.8100E-03 & 4.7700E-03 \\
150 & 4.5604E-04 & 3.2058E-04 & 8.7500E-03 & 8.0300E-03 & 6.7000E-03 \\
179 & 4.3677E-04 & 3.1865E-04 & 3.7120E-02 & 3.3240E-02 & 2.7470E-02 
        \end{tabular*}       \\
% second row
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             S[table-format=3.0] *{5}{S}}
    \midrule
{\phantom{Energy}}
    &   \multicolumn{5}{c}{\SI{8}{eV}}    \\
    \midrule
0   & 5.7298E-01 & 5.5016E-01 & 1.1880E-02 & 1.1770E-02 & 1.3400E-02 \\
5   & 4.8934E-01 & 4.6909E-01 & 2.0810E-02 & 2.0060E-02 & 1.9100E-02 \\
10  & 3.2654E-01 & 3.1181E-01 & 3.9750E-02 & 3.7990E-02 & 3.2860E-02 \\
15  & 1.8158E-01 & 1.7243E-01 & 5.1740E-02 & 4.9570E-02 & 4.2660E-02 \\
20  & 8.6570E-02 & 8.1660E-02 & 4.9830E-02 & 4.7940E-02 & 4.2040E-02 \\
30  & 1.2440E-02 & 1.1670E-02 & 2.6280E-02 & 2.5410E-02 & 2.3350E-02 \\
40  & 6.9667E-04 & 8.3683E-04 & 1.7960E-02 & 1.7190E-02 & 1.5500E-02 \\
60  & 1.9900E-03 & 1.8900E-03 & 1.7080E-02 & 1.6220E-02 & 1.4370E-02 \\
90  & 1.0200E-03 & 8.6751E-04 & 5.9800E-03 & 5.5900E-03 & 4.9800E-03 \\
120 & 2.7382E-04 & 2.1843E-04 & 5.5100E-03 & 5.1600E-03 & 4.4200E-03 \\
150 & 6.6697E-05 & 5.3188E-05 & 3.6600E-03 & 3.4200E-03 & 2.8800E-03 \\
179 & 2.4671E-05 & 2.1034E-05 & 6.2200E-03 & 5.6900E-03 & 4.5600E-03 
\end{tabular*}
    &   \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                     S[table-format=3.0] *{5}{S}}
    \midrule
{\phantom{Energy}}
    &   \multicolumn{5}{c}{\SI{8}{eV}}    \\
            \midrule
0   & 1.3462E+00 & 1.3165E+00 & 3.0895E-01 & 3.0683E-01 & 3.0356E-01 \\
5   & 9.9261E-01 & 9.6923E-01 & 2.6066E-01 & 2.5818E-01 & 2.5266E-01 \\
10  & 4.6491E-01 & 4.5206E-01 & 1.8738E-01 & 1.8494E-01 & 1.7725E-01 \\
15  & 1.7669E-01 & 1.7086E-01 & 1.2498E-01 & 1.2330E-01 & 1.1675E-01 \\
20  & 5.5270E-02 & 5.3160E-02 & 7.4620E-02 & 7.3710E-02 & 6.9690E-02 \\
30  & 1.7700E-03 & 1.8100E-03 & 2.4720E-02 & 2.4360E-02 & 2.3490E-02 \\
40  & 1.4000E-03 & 1.4400E-03 & 1.8440E-02 & 1.8000E-02 & 1.7160E-02 \\
60  & 2.0900E-03 & 1.9300E-03 & 4.4700E-03 & 4.3400E-03 & 4.2700E-03 \\
90  & 4.2589E-04 & 3.5884E-04 & 7.6401E-04 & 7.3017E-04 & 7.4240E-04 \\
120 & 8.3499E-05 & 6.4916E-05 & 2.4500E-03 & 2.2600E-03 & 2.0600E-03 \\
150 & 2.3065E-05 & 1.7681E-05 & 1.1620E-02 & 1.0910E-02 & 1.0110E-02 \\
179 & 1.1580E-05 & 8.7843E-06 & 1.9180E-02 & 1.7950E-02 & 1.7860E-02 
        \end{tabular*}       \\
% third row
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             S[table-format=3.0] *{5}{S}}
    \midrule
{\phantom{Energy}}
    &   \multicolumn{5}{c}{\SI{8}{eV}}    \\
    \midrule
0   & 2.0681E+00 & 2.0379E+00 & 8.3816E-01 & 8.3028E-01 & 7.8709E-01 \\
5   & 1.3276E+00 & 1.3066E+00 & 5.3780E-01 & 5.3224E-01 & 5.0531E-01 \\
10  & 4.4213E-01 & 4.3325E-01 & 1.9529E-01 & 1.9306E-01 & 1.8531E-01 \\
15  & 1.2783E-01 & 1.2462E-01 & 7.3720E-02 & 7.3030E-02 & 7.1870E-02 \\
20  & 2.6280E-02 & 2.5510E-02 & 3.7500E-02 & 3.7200E-02 & 3.6990E-02 \\
30  & 3.5382E-04 & 4.4318E-04 & 1.3700E-02 & 1.3480E-02 & 1.2870E-02 \\
40  & 2.6200E-03 & 2.5600E-03 & 3.9800E-03 & 4.0200E-03 & 4.8600E-03 \\
60  & 1.3700E-03 & 1.2600E-03 & 5.7300E-03 & 5.5400E-03 & 4.2200E-03 \\
90  & 1.8669E-04 & 1.5777E-04 & 4.1300E-03 & 3.9800E-03 & 3.0400E-03 \\
120 & 4.9810E-05 & 4.1139E-05 & 3.9300E-03 & 3.8300E-03 & 3.4900E-03 \\
150 & 2.3575E-05 & 1.9512E-05 & 4.2400E-03 & 4.1300E-03 & 3.9600E-03 \\
179 & 7.0379E-06 & 5.1833E-06 & 1.8350E-02 & 1.8090E-02 & 1.9810E-02 
\end{tabular*}
    &   \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                     S[table-format=3.0] *{5}{S}}
    \midrule
{\phantom{Energy}}
    &   \multicolumn{5}{c}{\SI{8}{eV}}    \\
            \midrule
0   & 2.6462E+00 & 2.6176E+00 & 1.3935E+00 & 1.3835E+00 & 1.3693E+00 \\
5   & 1.5237E+00 & 1.5059E+00 & 8.1023E-01 & 8.0398E-01 & 7.9459E-01 \\
10  & 3.6730E-01 & 3.6139E-01 & 2.1753E-01 & 2.1552E-01 & 2.1170E-01 \\
15  & 8.7530E-02 & 8.5710E-02 & 6.0390E-02 & 5.9740E-02 & 5.8150E-02 \\
20  & 1.0530E-02 & 1.0300E-02 & 2.6290E-02 & 2.5970E-02 & 2.5590E-02 \\
30  & 1.4300E-03 & 1.4700E-03 & 1.0410E-02 & 1.0330E-02 & 1.0180E-02 \\
40  & 2.8900E-03 & 2.8100E-03 & 4.1900E-03 & 4.1600E-03 & 3.9100E-03 \\
60  & 8.3774E-04 & 7.7585E-04 & 6.2500E-03 & 6.0900E-03 & 5.7600E-03 \\
90  & 1.0233E-04 & 8.8553E-05 & 5.9300E-03 & 5.7600E-03 & 5.5300E-03 \\
120 & 3.4667E-05 & 3.0188E-05 & 3.0400E-03 & 2.9600E-03 & 2.8500E-03 \\
150 & 1.5723E-05 & 1.3463E-05 & 4.2400E-03 & 4.1800E-03 & 3.8700E-03 \\
179 & 3.4073E-06 & 3.4427E-06 & 5.9900E-03 & 6.0000E-03 & 5.4200E-03 
        \end{tabular*}       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance

Comment: @NoahWilliam, does answer solve your problem? If you like answer, you should up-vote it (by clicking on up triangle at left top side of answer) or even accept it (clicking on check mark there).